# Google search results not showing up (but links are present)

Tags: google-chrome, search

My google search results (On both Chrome and IE) are coming up blank but the search results are there, confirmed by mouse hover.

[image]

The urls returned by the search are all accessible by mouse-hover but none of them are actually displaying on the page. 
I have tried clearing browser data (cache, cookies, temp files and history),flushing DNS, incognito mode in Chrome, run Anti-malware programs to see if any Malware is being responsible for this. None of them is working. Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using browser extensions? Try disabling or removing them.

Comment: I did, didn't solve the issue.